# How to properly configure loader for png in webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

This is what I tried in my Webpack project:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const UglifyJsPlugin = webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin;

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    button: glob.sync(`${__dirname}/components/index.js`),
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'components',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        rules: [{
          test: /\.js$/,
          loaders: ['babel-loader'],
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        query: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: './assets/media/',
              publicPath: './assets/media/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
  externals: [
    'prop-types',
    'react',
    'react-dom',
  ],
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true }),
  ],
};
```

In my js file I try to import and use a simple png like this:

```
import favicon from '../assets/media/star-full.png'
import beers from './beers.json'

<Card
  imgUrl={beer.image_url}
  name={beer.name}
  tagline={beer.tagline}
  iconFavorites={favicon}>
</Card>);
```

As per request my package.json file (in emphasis, I have installed `file-loader` 3.0.1):

```
{
  "name": "storybook-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/react": "^3.4.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^3.4.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/chenchi13/storybook-project.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/chenchi13/storybook-project/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/chenchi13/storybook-project#readme"
}
```

I keep getting the same error, I get that it's probably due to this Webpack configuration but I have no clue what I'm supposed to do... All other questions about the same issue don't properly explain the proper way to configure Webpack, since most of the answers are partial and don't give me enough insight to resolve this issue.

Comment: You should also add the webpack version you use, IMHO.

Comment: You should also post entire package.json configuration, not just the single loader.

Comment: updated the question with full package.json and webpack.config.js files